# How to get a green certificate bar if I'm not a company?

Tags: tls, cryptography, certificates, http

I'm not a company and do not represent one, but I would like to have a green bar on my website for several reasons. One of them, for example, is that I want to ensure that the information displayed in the page is really from me, and any other reasons to ensure trust for anyone who's reading it. I know that these types of certificate are called Extended Validation Certificates. I googled how I could get one as a individual and I found [this](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9470/68/can-i-get-an-ovev-certificate-if-i-apply-as-an-individual-and-dont-have-a-registered-organization). It says here that I could get a OV. But it will not say if I'll get a green bar or so.

How can somebody, say, a journalist, get a green bar cerficate for its blog to ensure that its his real blog? How can a security analyst ensure that it's his website that people are visiting? How can someone ensure that a person is not visiting a URL thats similar to yours? How can I know that I'm not accessing for example googIe.com instead of google.com? (some URLs do really look alike when some letters are replaced by similar ones).

I can think of a lot of applications for this, in that they do not need to be a company but need to be trusted more than a simple automatically generated certificate.

Comment: OV certs won't do it. You need an EV. I believe you need to have some business, even a sole proprietorship, to get one.

Answer (score 7):

Refer to the [guidelines](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/EV-SSL-Certificate-Guidelines-Version-1.4.6.pdf) set up by the CA/Browser forum for extended validation.

> 8.5.1 General
>
> The CA MAY only issue EV Certificates to Applicants that meet the
>   Private Organization, Government Entity,Business Entity and
>   Non-Commercial Entity requirements specified below.
>
> 8.5.2 Private Organization Subjects An Applicant qualifies as a Private Organization if:
>
> (1) The entity’s legal existence is created or recognized by a by a
>   filing with (or an act of) the Incorporating  or Registration Agency
>   in its Jurisdiction of Incorporation or Registration (e.g., by
>   issuance of a certificate of incorporation, registration number, etc.)
>   or created or recognized by a Government  Agency (e.g. under a
>   charter, treaty, convention, or equivalent recognition instrument);
>
> (2) The entity designated with the Incorporating or Registration
>   Agency a Registered Agent, a Registered Office (as required under the
>   laws of the Jurisdiction ofIncorporation or Registration), or an
>   equivalent facility;
>
> (3) The entity is not designated on the records of the Incorporating
>   or Registration Agency by labels such as “inactive,” “invalid,” “not
>   current,” or the equivalent;
>
> (4) The entity has a verifiable physical existence and business
>   presence;
>
> (5) The entity’s Jurisdiction of Incorporation, Registration, Charter,
>   or License, and/or its Place of Business is not in any country where
>   the CA is prohibited from doing business or issuing a certificate by
>   the laws of the CA’s jurisdiction; and
>
> (6) The entity is not listed on any government denial list or
>   prohibited list (e.g., trade embargo) under the laws of the CA’s
>   jurisdiction.